# Is there a way to clear the terminal on webpack hot reload?

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

I want to clear Unix terminal on Webpack hot reloading so that I have a fresh terminal after the reload.

Comment: i want the opposite. prevent webpack from clearing the terminal. i hate my job ^^

Comment: May be this npm package can help you?
https://github.com/danillouz/clean-terminal-webpack-plugin

Comment: @phil294 Given that it's been 3 years since your comment I assume you've already found the answer. But if not, do the following grep through your "node_modules" folder: `grep -rn "\[2J"`, and just disable whatever line is issuing the console clear command! In my case the culprit was actually "jest-cli".